# Multiple map on array React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native

Use multiple Map on array. I get error:
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Laptop15\Desktop\React Native\src\screens\Question.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (59:7)

I use function that: {PytaniePush(quizDane.quest1)}

```
   function PytaniePush(myID) {
            if(quizDane && quizDane.quest1 && myID){
                myID.map((item, key)=>(
                    myID[key].map((item2, key2)=>(
                        return ({RadioPush(myID[key].item2)});
                    ));
                )); 
            }
        }
```

I want to console log with all elements in array and object:
quest1->array[Object(A,B), Object(A,B)]
Data look: [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdAiS.jpg)
I want to get:
A in 0 is ...
B in 0 is ...
A in 1 is ...
B in 1 is ...

Answer (score 0):

You have an syntax error in your code. Here is right code.

```
function PytaniePush(myID) {
  if (quizDane && quizDane.quest1 && myID) {
    myID.map((item, key) =>
      myID[key].map((item2, key2) => {
        return RadioPush(myID[key].item2);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Next time when you will have a syntax error try to use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) to find error and improve format of your code.

Comment: Thanks! next problem: TypeError: myID[key].map is not a function. (In 'myID[key].map(function (item2, key2) {
            return RadioPush(myID[key].item2);
          })', 'myID[key].map' is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code. Try this one.

```
function PytaniePush(myID) {
  if(quizDane && quizDane.quest1 && myID){
    myID.map((item, key) => myID[key].map((item2, key2) => { 
      return RadioPush(myID[key].item2);
    } ));
  }
}
```

Try to use an ES6 aware IDE. That way you will not stumble upon this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks! next problem: TypeError: myID[key].map is not a function. (In 'myID[key].map(function (item2, key2) { return RadioPush(myID[key].item2); })', 'myID[key].map' is undefined)

Comment: is `myID[key]` an array? what is your expected result? Please update the question with what you expect as a result. I guess that you are trying to iterate with `map` over an Object

Comment: done, I want to iterate objects in array and show values of elements